# Codeigniter, using if statement .. how to make it more simple?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Codeigniter, using if statement .. how to make it more simple?

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!="" && $this->session->userdata('stts')=="x")
{
  Do action
}
else if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!="" && $this->session->userdata('stts')=="y")
{
  Do action
}
else if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!="" && $this->session->userdata('stts')=="z")
{
  Do action
}
else
{
 done 
}
```

Comment: using switch case you can beautify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != "" && in_array($this->session->userdata('stts'), ['x', 'y', 'z']))
{
    //Do action
}
else
{
    //done
}
```

Comment: this assumes that x,y,z should all do the same function. if that is the case, than this is a good answer.

Comment: i think thats the answer for my question :D.. Big thanks mate

Answer (score 3):

You could use a switch

```
  if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!="" ) {

     switch ($this->session->userdata('stts'){
        case "x":
          Do action for x 
          break;
        case "y":
          Do action for y
          break;
        case "z":
          Do action for z 
          break;   
        default:
          Do action for othes 
          break;   
     }

  } else {
   // done

 }
```

Comment: @Alex   .. else added

Answer (score 2):

You can use switch case like this :

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!=""){
        switch($this->session->userdata('stts')){
            case "x":
                // Do action
                break;
            case "y":
                // Do action
                break;
            case "z":
                // Do action
                break;
            default:
                // Do action
                break;

        }

    }
else{
//if session not set
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: if i can ask one more thing .. what if the actions are same for all cases ?.. sorry btw .. im a newbie :)

Comment: that kindof information is what should have been stated at the start as it yields a completely different answer ;) if all the actions are the same use Shamkhal Maharramov answer

Comment: :D .. sorry mate .. im completely new to this kind of things

Answer (score 1):

using switch case you more beautify it.

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')!="")
{
   switch($this->session->userdata('stts'))
   {
       case "x":
             //do some thing
         break;
       case "y":
             //do some thing
         break;
       case "z":
             //do some thing
         break;
       default:
           //do some thing
   }

} else {
  // else condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple if/else and [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') != "") {
    switch ($this->session->userdata('stts')) {
        case 'x':
            // do action
            break;
        case 'y':
            // do action
            break;
        case 'z':
            // do action
            break;
        default:
            // if neither x,y,z are stts
            break;
    }
} else {
    // done
}
```

Comment: ty guys .. appreciate for ur quick responses